# DocuSign Authentication Error - dsPrepare not defined

Tags: docusignapi

I saw similar post previously but there was no solution provided, resubmitting the same issue here asking for help please.

When signing in DocuSign, most of the time it just times out (spinning circle) or I will get the error below:

dsPrepare is not defined.

This happens when I connect to corporate network but seems ok when i switch to my own hotspot.

Any idea what might be causing the error above?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your corporate network may have a filter applied that blocks traffic from certain unknown IP Addresses. This would usually cause regular DocuSign processes from completing successfully. You can ask your IT Team to allowlist DocuSign's domains which are listed [here](https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Karan, I am not so sure as the website was able to be accessed just that it takes an awful long time and most of the time it timeout and failed. Some of the time I am able to access fine after 20 mins.

Comment: Interesting, 20 minutes is a long time for a page to load. If it is only affecting your connection through your corporate network, would still be worth chatting with your IT team on potential causes for this.